# Import gmail message to spreadsheet and on next script run only get new messages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm importing emails from a specific label to a spreadsheet, but it is not efficient to load all the e-mails on every script run.

I have searched and searched but can't find a solution for only getting new messages.

The approach i would like to be able to take is:
Check lastrow of spreadsheet with emails-> check amount of messages.
append rows with new messages ("messages" - last row).

I hope someone has a solution to this, it would be a massive impact on the finalization of what i want to create! Thanks in advance!

I'm a noob coder but created the following script to get the amount of messages:

```
function messageCount(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var label = ss.getRange('A1').getValue().toString();

var array = new Array();

var threads = GmailApp.search("in:" + label);

for(var n in threads){

var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
var threadCount = threads[n].getMessageCount();
array.push(threadCount);

}

var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

count = count + array[i];
}
var currentTransactions = count;
Logger.log(currentTransactions);
```

}

Comment: Why not store the IDs of the threads in the sheet, or in the PropertiesService? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getId() If the ID of the message you grab is already in the array of stored IDs, skip that iteration in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Ill try and see which one will suit best and post my findings!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a label (say Counted) that keeps track of the processed message. Apply the label to threads that have been counted and ignore these in the next run.

```
function messageCount(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var label = ss.getRange('A1').getValue().toString();
  var processed = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Counted") || GmailApp.createLabel("Counted");
  var threads = GmailApp.search("-in:Counted in:" + label);
  var count = 0;

  for(var t in threads){    
    count += threads[t].getMessageCount();    
    threads[t].addLabel(processed);
  }

  Logger.log(count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amit! Have to say, your site labnol.org is my starting page :) ill submit my findings when i have completed my "app".

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different solution.
I am not sure if the email id's have a logical order, so I figured that the only logical thing to do is sort the emails by JS time (milliseconds).

What i have done is:
- Get all the emails and turn them in to an object. with the property key being the JS time.
- Place all the objects in a sheet
- on the next run, check if there is a difference between the length in sheet vs the new email batch
- if so: oldbatch-newbatch (length).
- sort the new array with JS time
- match the JS time with the property keys and execute a object method that returns the mailid's from the new received messages

It might not be efficientt, but it gets the job done. You can check the code here (abnMailMoneyFetcher()):[GAS](https://script.google.com/macros/d/Mu5RMMoM6AnrL6-Sn3HjaOJ83auf4GSoO/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvHR3QpnLLoFPAPoJb8C7a-98YPokvcy0elI4S4Q_2Jxj4oei9bIvI_cu7iuQ88I-yofNm_QrXN6n5AsbC4hBtE_Pt6kTOAeIXkNpofrRkzLPi9t6wi4jy7FvKMZ9vo8eHgSj_6vMosedit?usp=sharing)